# Using different references in Visual Studio 2010 for different build platforms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, multiplatform

How do I set up a VS2010 project so that it uses different references based on the chosen platform?
In practice, I would like to link a 32-bit library when I choose x86 as platform, but the 64-bit version of it when I choose x64.

Any idea on how to get this swap done for a C# VS2010 project?

Comment: Just don't.  The 32-bit and 64-bit versions should contain the same types so it doesn't matter.  Metadata is not architecture dependent.  Pick AnyCPU for libraries, only the setting for the main EXE project counts.

Comment: I don't have a choice in the matter, the libs are either 32-bit or 64-bit, there is no AnyCPU (because of native dll integration)

Comment: @Hans I'm having to solve the same issue - I have a native library for which I have C++/CLI wrapper (having two versions of that is no problem - it uses the C++ build system). But then I have a C# application which references that wrapper - and I have to choose between 32 (compatibility) or 64 (less memory limitations), but I can't have both because of the issue OP faces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference different version of dll with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997268/how-to-reference-different-version-of-dll-with-msbuild)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but possibly you'll need to edit the project file and hack the Conditions into the ItemGroup with the references.

Here you go, found an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997268/how-to-reference-different-version-of-dll-with-msbuild) with the answer.