# VB.net Reference path changes depending on 32 or 64 bit system

Tags: vb.net, dll, reference

I am building a program in VB.net which uses a program called Grapher (Golden Software) to make graphs.

On my computer (64 bit), it works perfectly, and the reference in my project is to `Program Files (x86)\GoldenSoftware\...`

However, in my colleague's computer (32 bit), it doesn't work. I think it is because of the way it is referenced in my project. On their computer, it is located in `Program Files\GoldenSoftware\...`

Is there a way I can:

1. Change the reference path on runtime
2. Add both references to my project and only use the one which exists
3. Do something even better?

Thanks.

Comment: copy both dlls to your exe dir, rename appropriately and use  something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997268/how-to-reference-different-version-of-dll-with-msbuild/1998436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the colleague had a "broken" version of Grapher which didn't even have the dll I needed.

All we had to do was copy the GoldenSoftware folder from program files (x86) to non-x86 program files.

Answer (score 1):

Some options are:

1. Install the assembly into the same folder as the exe
2. Install the assembly into the Global Assembly Cache
3. Specify codeBase tags in the application config file
4. Use the AssemblyResolve event

For details of items 2 -4 see this microsoft document: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

Comment: Thanks Matt. It turns out that the colleague had a "broken" version of Grapher which didn't even have the dll I needed. All we had to do was copy the GoldenSoftware from x86 to non-x86.